# Problem with infinite scroll on multisite with custom query

Tags: wp-query, multisite, infinite-scroll

I have a WordPress Multisite that uses a special query that combines all the posts on the network and uses the main site to display all posts in the network.

Anyway, I would like to have my site use infinite scroll. No matter what plugins I use, it won't use infinite scroll.

Here's how the query works on my site:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<section id="index">
<div class="container"> 
<div class="main"> 
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; $args = array( 'multisite' => 1, 'sites__not_in' => array(1), 'paged' => $paged, ); $query = new WP_Query( $args ); while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?> 

<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?> <?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php if (is_front_page() ) { ?> <nav id="first-nav"> <?php next_posts_link( 'load more', $query->max_num_pages ); ?> </nav> <?php } else { ;?> <nav id="navigate"> <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous' );next_posts_link( 'Next', $query->max_num_pages ); ?> </nav> <?php } ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
</div> </div> </section> 
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinite scroll usually requires some kind of Javascript library to load more results via [Ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX). The basic idea is this:

- User arrives at your page, you show, say, 5 posts per page
- They scroll past a certain offset and you use JavaScript to trigger an Ajax request
- Your request passes the requested paged, the endpoint receives the request, and returns just the HTML of the posts you want.
- You handle the Ajax response and insert the HTML in to the page

[Here is a good writeup](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/pagination-infinite-scrolling-load-more-buttons/) from Smashing Magazine on how to determine if infinite scrolling, pagination, or "Load More" is best for you.

Some other tips:

- You probably **don't** want to load all posts at once - this may not be an issue now, or for a long time, but eventually this will come back to bite you
- There are plenty of plugins and tutorials for doing this, you just need a good understanding of how it works

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to go with "load more" clicking option but the code I"m using doesn't work, click on load more and nothing happends.

Index.php:

```
<div id="content">
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
'multisite' => 1,
'sites__not_in' => array(1),
'paged' => $paged,);
$loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<?php while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();  ?>
<p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>  

<a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

At the bottom of Index.php:

```
var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
var page = 1; // What page we are on.
var ppp = 3; // Post per page

$("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ // When btn is pressed.
    $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true); // Disable the button, temp.
    $.post(ajaxUrl, {
        action:"more_post_ajax",
        offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
        ppp: ppp
    }).success(function(posts){
        page++;
        $("#content").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
    });

});
```

And on my functions.php:

```
function more_post_ajax(){
$offset = $_POST["offset"];
$ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
header("Content-Type: text/html");

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'offset' => $offset,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
   the_content();
}

exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.